# beautifulSoup screenscraping list of improperly nested <ul>s

Tags: python, screen-scraping, beautifulsoup, web-scraping

I'm (very) new to BeautifulSoup, and for the last three days trying to get a list of churches from http://www.ucanews.com/diocesan-directory/html/ordinary-of-philippine-cagayandeoro-parishes.html.

It seems that data is not properly nested but only tagged for presentation purposes only. Supposedly, the hierarchical structure is

```
Parishes
    District
    (data)
        Vicariate
        (data)
            Church
            (data)
```

However all I see are that every church starts with a bullet, and each entry is separated by two line breaks. The field names I'm after is italicized and separated from the actual data with a ":". Each unit entry (District |Vicariate|Parish) may have one or more data fields.

So far, I could tease some of the data out, but I couldn't get the name of entity to show up.

```
soup=BeautifulSoup(page)
for e in soup.table.tr.findAll('i'):
    print e.string, e.nextSibling
```

Finally,I'm hoping to transform the data column-wise: `district, vicariate, parish, address, phone, titular, parish priest, <field8>, <field9>, <field99>`

Would appreciate a good nudge in the right direction.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately this is going to be a little complicated because this format has some of the data you need uncontained by clear markers.

### Data Model

Also, your understanding of the nesting is not entirely correct. Actual Catholic church structure (not this document structure) is more like:

```
District (also called deanery or vicariate. In this case they all seem to be Vicariates Forane.)
    Cathedral, Parish, Oratory
```

Note that there is *no requirement* that a Parish fall under a district/deanery, although they usually do. I think the document is saying that everything listed after a District belongs to that district, but you can't know for sure.

There's also an entry in there that is not a Church but a community (San Lorenzo Filipino-Chinese Community). These have no distinct identity or governance in the church (i.e. it's not a building)--rather, it's a non-territorial group of people that a Chaplain is assigned to care for.

### Parsing

I think you should take an incremental approach:

1. find all the `li` elements, each of which is an "item"
2. the name of the item is the first text node
3. find all the `i` elements: these are keys, attribute values, column rows, etc
4. all the text up to the next `i` (separated by `br`) is a value for that key.

**One special problem with this page is that its html is *so pathologically bad* that you need to use `MinimalSoup` to parse it correctly.** In particular, `BeautifulSoup` thinks the `li` elements are nested because there's no `ol` or `ul` anywhere in the document!

**This code will give you a list of lists of tuples. Each tuple is a `('key','value')` pair for an item.**

Once you have this data structure, you can normalize, transform, nest, etc, however you like, and leave the HTML behind.

```
from BeautifulSoup import MinimalSoup
import urllib

fp = urllib.urlopen("http://www.ucanews.com/diocesan-directory/html/ordinary-of-philippine-cagayandeoro-parishes.html")
html = fp.read()
fp.close()

soup = MinimalSoup(html);

root = soup.table.tr.td

items = []
currentdistrict = None
# this loops through each "item"
for li in root.findAll(lambda tag: tag.name=='li' and len(tag.attrs)==0):
    attributes = []
    parishordistrict = li.next.strip()
     # look for string "district" to determine if district; otherwise it's something else under the district
    if parishordistrict.endswith(' District'):
        currentdistrict = parishordistrict
        attributes.append(('_isDistrict',True))
    else:
        attributes.append(('_isDistrict',False))

    attributes.append(('_name',parishordistrict))
    attributes.append(('_district',currentdistrict))

    # now loop through all attributes of this thing
    attributekeys = li.findAll('i')

    for i in attributekeys:
        key = i.string # normalize as needed. Will be 'Address:', 'Parochial Victor:', etc
        # now continue among the siblings until we reach an <i> again.
        # these are "values" of this key
        # if you want a nested key:[values] structure, you can use a dict,
        # but beware of multiple <i> with the same name in your logic
        next = i.nextSibling
        while next is not None and getattr(next, 'name', None) != 'i':
            if not hasattr(next, 'name') and getattr(next, 'string', None):
                value = next.string.strip()
                if value:
                    attributes.append((key, value))
            next = next.nextSibling
    items.append(attributes)

from pprint import pprint
pprint(items)
```

Comment: Thank you Francis. Allow me some time to study your code so I can learn from it. btw, when I mentioned the hierarchy, I was referring to it in the context of the page. I appreciate the clarification.

Comment: Ah, in that case the `li` nesting is merely because of how the `BeautifulSoup` parser interprets the awful html. Using `MinimalSoup` parser turns the nested `li`s into a flat list of `li`, which is how most browsers will construct the DOM tree.

Comment: Francis,

I made a few minor tweaks but your code did all the (very) dirty work. Re "pathologically bad" html. I thought so myself, but that's probably better than the first page I found http://claretianpublications.com/index.php/diocese/505-archdiocese-of-cagayan-de-oro

I appreciate your effort and  assistance with BeautifulSoup. Thank you very much.